# define geo index in ArangoDB

Tags: geolocation, location, arangodb, aql

I have a data structure like below. how can I define a geo index for that structure?

```
{
  "currentGeoLocation": {
    "latitude": -10,
    "longitude": 1
  }
}
```

I tried these command:
1-

```
db.test.ensureIndex({ type: "geo", fields: [ "currentGeoLocation[latitude]","currentGeoLocation[longitude]" ] });
```

2-

```
 db.test.ensureIndex({ type: "geo", fields: [ "currentGeoLocation.latitude","currentGeoLocation.longitude" ] });
```

but I think none works correctly. because after I search the nearest items, I got [].
whats the problem?

Comment: Did the answers work for you? if yes, can you mark the best of them as 'accepted'? If not, whats missing? Would you like to share your actual solution?

Answer (score 3):

Your second index creation is the correct one.

One has to know, that latitude and longtitude aren't actualy km units. Entering `[-10, 1]` into [a distance calculator](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) (which also is a good read about the calculation details) tells you its `1117 km` away from `[0,0]`. Since the unit of the radius is `m` in ArangoDB, the numbers get big.

Searching at the actual spot will for sure find your item:

```
db._query('FOR item IN WITHIN(test, -10, 1, 1) RETURN item').toArray()
```

But, searching from `[0,0]` requires a bigger radius:

```
db._query('FOR item IN WITHIN(test, 0, 0, 1200000) RETURN item').toArray()
[ 
  { 
    "_key" : "840", 
    "_id" : "test/840", 
    "_rev" : "840", 
    "currentGeoLocation" : { 
      "latitude" : -10, 
      "longitude" : 1 
    } 
  } 
]
```

Comment: running into the same problem, if coordinates are nested like in this question the query does not work. However if we define the geo index on collection where the data is not nested the query works.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the previous answer, are you using the arangosh interface or arangodb js?

I ask as the arangodb js interface is different. In this case you would look at something like:

```
db.collection('testnodes').createGeoIndex(['currentGeoLocation.latitude', 'currentGeoLocation.longitude'])
```

Also, arangodb does then come with a number of really quite useful Geolocation functions (near, within etc) which have a helper function  to automatically calculate the distance.